# SAS/SQL - Create a Column that shows the number of times a value has occurred

Tags: sql, sas

I have a table with an account number and several attributes.

**acct | attr1 |  attr2 | attr3...**

The issue is that there are duplicate account numbers in the list with different attributes. To make matters worse, when there are two account number entries, those entries may have entirely different attributes.

I have a sorting scheme to use to somewhat solve the issue, but after I sort the table, I only need the **first occurrence** of each account number. I am attempting to do this in sas using Proc SQL.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: First isn't a good concept in SQL because row order is not enforced, a data step is much easier when the order of the data matters.

Comment: The question title seems rather out of step with the body text.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to do this with `PROC SQL`, however in `DATA STEP` logic it is possible.

After the data is sorted, use `first.` (pronounced first-dot) logic to pick the first occurrence:

First sort the data, using your desired scheme.

```
proc sort data=have out=intermediate_table;
  by acct <other variables>;
run;
```

Then just use `first.acct`:

```
data want;
  set intermediate_table;
  by acct <other variables>;
  if first.acct then output;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

proc sort is easiest way to do this. You can use undocumented monotonic() function to do this in Proc sql as shown below

```
data have;
input acct attr1 $ attr2 $ attr3 $;
datalines;
100 a b c
100 b d e
100 c e f
101 a b c
102 h i j
102 h k l
 ;

proc sql;
create table want(drop =rn) as 
select * from 
(select b.*,monotonic() as rn
 from have b)
group by acct
having rn =min(rn);
```

or by using *n* in a datastep(creating view is a good option as suggested @richard in comments sections)followed by group by as shown below.

```
data have_view/view=have_view;;
set have;
rn=_n_;
run; 

proc sql;
create table want as 
select acct, attr1 , attr2 , attr3
from have_view b
group by acct
having rn =min(rn);
```

Comment: why replicate the entire original data ? `have1` should be a view, `data have_view/view=have_view; set have; my_row_number = _n_; run;`